# What is the setting that changes wire frame thickness?

Tags: 3d-view, customization, wireframe

[image]

Hi definition display makes my wire frame very very thin, is there a setting in blender that increases the visibility for wire frame?

Comment: @ cegaton Hi, DPI doesn't change wire frame thickness it only changes the menu panels in the gui.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In settings under system there is an option called "Virtual Pixel Mode".  Setting this to Double will increase the line width.  It also increases the size of the the UI elements, but on a high DPI display that's probably not a bad thing.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes this WORKS!! Here is a before and after with high dpi setting no double and double with low dpi. Thank you! http://imgur.com/a/21tfn

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is in Blender 3.0 and newer: go to Blender `Preferences > Interface > Display` and click `Line Width` to choose between:

- Thin
- Default
- Thick