# Where is the "Virtual Pixel Mode" option?

Tags: 3d-view, customization, wireframe

I'm searching for an option to make shown wireframe thicker. I found one solution there [What is the setting that changes wire frame thickness?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81337/what-is-the-setting-that-changes-wire-frame-thickness), but I can't find that Virtual Pixel Mode switch in my System options.
[image]

Upd: Another option (Line width) seems do something similar , but it changes some GUI parameters and vertex sizes too.
[image]

How to change edge widths only or is there a way to change back the GUI lines and Vertex sizes without changing edge widths? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setting has been renamed in the most recent builds (also Blender 2.80 series) to `Line Width`. You can find it in the `Interface` section. Possible settings are `Thick`, `Thin` or `Auto`:

[image: line width setting]

Comment: I've updated the question. Vertex sizes and GUI lines changes too. Do you know that "Virtual Pixel Size" did exactly the similar as "Line width"?